# Target and color specific parts of a string

Tags: python, string, colorama

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()

question_four = "\n4. After you have died, what would you most like people to do when they hear your name? \n"
answers_four = ["ASK for more stories about your adventures", "i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts", "Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements", "MISS you, but smile"]

answers_house_a = ["ask", ...]
answers_house_b = ["don't care", ...]
answers_house_c = ["admiration", ...]
answers_house_d = ["miss", ...]
```

I would like to color the **CAPITALIZED words** within the variable `answers_four`. As I have 20 of those question variables and 20 related answers lists, adding `Fore.CYAN + "String" + Fore.RESET` to each word I want to color is not an option. Below is what I have managed so far which is printing the answers in cyan but not the specific parts of the strings.

```
for x in answers_four:
   print(f"{Fore.CYAN}" + x)
```

Prints (in cyan):

```
ASK for more stories about your adventures
i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts
Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements
MISS you, but smile
```

Comment: do you want to color the words in the 20 lists or just the capitalized words in answers_four?

Comment: Just the capitalized words in answers_four!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but I think what you're asking is for every capitalized word in `answer_four` to be printed in cyan (and for every other word to be printed normally).

You could do this like this:

```py
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
colorama.init()

answers_four = ["ASK for more stories about your adventures", "i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts", "Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements", "MISS you, but smile"]

for line in answers_four:
    for word in line.split():
        if word.isupper():
            print(Fore.CYAN + word + Fore.RESET, end=" ")

        else:
            print(word, end=" ")

    print()
```

Output:

```
ASK for more stories about your adventures 
i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts 
Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements 
MISS you, but smile
```

(You can't copy colored text into the question, but it colors the capitalized words cyan.)

You could also do this more concisely, for example like this:

```py
import colorama
from colorama import Fore


colorama.init()

answers_four = ["ASK for more stories about your adventures", "i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts", "Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements", "MISS you, but smile"]
answers_four = "\n".join(answers_four)  # make answers_four into a string, rather than a list

answers_four = " ".join(
    word if not word.isupper()
    else Fore.CYAN + word + Fore.RESET for word in answers_four.split(" ")
    )


print(answers_four)
```

**EDIT**

From the OP's comments, I understand that they have a list of lists storing their sentences, and wish for that to be printed:

```py
answers_house_a = ["ask", ...]
answers_house_b = ["don't care", ...]
answers_house_c = ["admiration", ...]
answers_house_d = ["miss", ...]
```

This could be done in multiple ways, for example:

```py
# add newlines to the end of the lists
answers_house_a = ["ask", ..., "\n"]
answers_house_b = ["don't care", ..., "\n"]
answers_house_c = ["admiration", ..., "\n"]
answers_house_d = ["miss", ..., "\n"]

# store all the words in one list, using list unpacking
answers_four = [*answers_house_a, *answers_house_b, *answers_house_c, *answers_house_d]

# make answers_four into a string, rather than a list
# note that now it is " ".join() not "\n".join() because each item is a word, not a line
answers_four = " ".join(answers_four)  

answers_four = " ".join(
    word if not word.isupper()
    else Fore.CYAN + word + Fore.RESET for word in answers_four.split(" ")
    )

print(answers_four)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! As I have 20 of those answers variables I need to target them all at once. I was thinking of putting all answers lists into a big list, like this: all_answers = [["FIRE", "Water", "AIR", "Earth"], ["The BOLD", "The Great", "The WISE", "The Good"], ["Glory", "POWER", "Wisdom", "LOVE"]].  ...and then unpack them with *args like this: [print(*a) for a in all_answers]. I have been struggling though to figure out the right syntax to combine this idea with your suggestion. Could you help out once more?

Comment: *As I have 20 of those answers variables I need to target them all at once.* I believe the answers here targets them all at once except if I'm not understanding you. You can put all your answers in list `answers_four`. I upvoted because I think this is a Nice question. BTW, you just need to be clear so I can understand this additional request

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I have the following variables: answers_one, answers_two, answers_three, ... answers_twenty. And each of those variables has a list with 4-7 elements. So all those elements of each list need to be targeted.

Comment: You can greatly simplify the test by changing `all(c not in ascii_lowercase for c in word)` to `word.isupper()`. Yes, it'll work ok with "DON'T" etc.

Comment: @rafaela, you should replace all those variables with a list of lists, then you can do the whole thing with an extra for-loop. But that's a separate problem from the one sbottingota solved for you.

Comment: Ok, Have you tried what @alexis suggested? Try that first and let us know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rafaela I edited my answer. Please see whether the updated section of my answer is what you're asking. I made a list of all answers (list of lists), then looped through and targeted the capitalized words in every list. I'm guessing that's what you want. Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted @sbottingota answer because I believe it resolves the original question. You can also do this with regex by finding the matching patterns and coloring the capitalized words in the list. See it below:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import re

colorama.init()

question_four = "\n4. After you have died, what would you most like people to do when they hear your name? \n"
answers_four = ["ASK for more stories about your adventures", "i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts", "Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements", "MISS you, but smile"]

ans_str = ' '.join(answers_four)
re_str = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9.,\']*', ans_str)
result = [Fore.CYAN + x + Fore.RESET if x.upper() in re_str else x for x in re_str]

print(' '.join(result))
```

**EDIT:**
Based on additional requests from OP in the comments. My understanding of OP's question is OP wants to know how to target every capitalized word in several answer lists. I did this by combining all the answers list into a single list, looping through and targeting the capitalized words using regex. See the solution below:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import re

colorama.init()

answers_house_a = ["ASK for more stories about your adventures"]
answers_house_b = ["i DON'T CARE what people think of me after I'm dead, it's what they think of me while I'm alive that counts"]
answers_house_c = ["Think with ADMIRATION of your achievements"]
answers_house_d = ["MISS you, but smile"]

all_answers_list = [answers_house_a, answers_house_b, answers_house_c, answers_house_d]

for ans in all_answers_list:
    ans_str = ' '.join(ans)
    re_str = re.findall(r'[\w,.?\-\']*', ans_str)
    result = [Fore.CYAN + x + Fore.RESET if x.upper() in re_str else x for x in re_str]
    print(' '.join(result))
```

You can try adding more lists to `all_answers_list` or even more words to each list and see that it works.